# Combine each value with each value from multiple columns in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to combine each value from one column with each value from another column in another sheet. Some initial data:

- I have 5 sheets in an Excel file.
- Each sheet has few columns. I'm interested in one column from each sheet (it's column C)
- Sheet1 has 3 rows

| header A | Another header B | Yet another header C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | AAA-0001 |
| Second | row | AAA-0002 |
| Third | row | AAA-0003 |

- Sheet2 has 5 rows

| header A | Another header B | Yet another header C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| asdadsfd | row | BBB-0001 |
| rgtrts | row | BBB-0002 |
| xcvxcv | row | BBB-0003 |
| xadwxcv | row | BBB-0004 |
| xcasdsd | row | BBB-0005 |

Now, I'm looking to get something like this

| data |
| --- |
| AAA-0001BBB-0001 |
| AAA-0001BBB-0002 |
| AAA-0001BBB-0003 |
| AAA-0001BBB-0004 |
| AAA-0001BBB-0005 |
| AAA-0002BBB-0001 |
| AAA-0002BBB-0002 |
| AAA-0002BBB-0003 |
| AAA-0002BBB-0004 |
| AAA-0002BBB-0005 |
| AAA-0003BBB-0001 |
| AAA-0003BBB-0002 |
| AAA-0003BBB-0003 |
| AAA-0003BBB-0004 |
| AAA-0003BBB-0005 |
| ... |

Above shows combined data from only two sheets. I have 5 sheets that I want to combine data like that from. So a resulting value would be more like

```
AAA-0001BBB-0001CCC-0001DDD-0001EEE-0001
AAA-0001BBB-0001CCC-0001DDD-0001EEE-0002
```

Is this possible within Excel and how to do it?
I have Office 365, so I assume it's the latest version. I don't have any plugins installed.

Comment: So you want all the possible combinations of the values in the 5 sheets? That's likely a lot of values.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Although you can do this with formulas, it would probably be easier with VBA or Power Query.  Work something up then edit your question if you run into problems.

Comment: @DS_London If he has five tables with 100 entries each, that would be ten million combinations.  Maybe Excel is not the best application, depending on the details.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes, that was what I was driving at.

Comment: I have 5 sheets with anything between 5 and 20 rows. Do you say that I should export this to CSV and write some script in Node or Python?

Answer (score 0):

`=LET(a,A1#,b,B1#,c,C1#,d,D1#,e,E1#, ra,ROWS(a),rb,ROWS(b),rc,ROWS(c),rd,ROWS(d),re,ROWS(e), seq,SEQUENCE(ra*rb*rc*rd*re), ma,MOD(seq-1,ra)+1,mb,MOD(seq-1,rb)+1,mc,MOD(seq-1,rc)+1,md,MOD(seq-1,rd)+1,me,MOD(seq-1,re)+1,  resa,ROUNDUP(seq/(rb*rc*rd*re),0),resb,MOD(ROUNDUP(seq/(rc*rd*re),0)-1,rb)+1,resc,MOD(ROUNDUP(seq/(rd*re),0)-1,rc)+1,resd,MOD(ROUNDUP(seq/(re),0)-1,rd)+1,rese,MOD(ROUNDUP(seq,0)-1,re)+1, CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5},INDEX(a,resa),INDEX(b,resb),INDEX(c,resc),INDEX(d,resd),INDEX(e,rese)))`

Where you need to change `A1#` for your range of  column C in Sheet1, `B1#` for range column C in Sheet2, etc..

This spills the result down and to the right.

But VBA solution would be better.